# Codeigniter update only the first row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, foreach

I'm trying to update a column in the MySQL table by using CodeIgniter's "update" active record. However, I can only update the first row of the array I put in. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
       $invalid_email_raw='raphael@live.com;
                           fadfds@qq.com;
                           fsd@qq.com;
                           df@qq.com';

       $invalid_email=explode(';', $invalid_email_raw);

       foreach ($invalid_email as $email):

            $data=array(
                'status'=>'unsubscribed'
                );

            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->update('user', $data);

        endforeach;
```

Essentially, the code breaks the 4 emails into an array, and uses foreach to update the corresponding status where the email is found.

However, only the status for "raphael@live.com" is updated. All the other 3 are unchanged.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you do a single query instead?

Comment: not sure how to do that...mind showing an example?

Comment: In a single query you can do it with batch update [$this->db->update_batch();](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: thanks but due to my limited skill I still can't figure out the exact way. An answer with this approach to my question is much appreciated!

Comment: See `Parag Tyagi` answer below. This is how you do it. It also executes faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are using newlines, which after explode you have:

`raphael@live.com`
`\nfadfds@qq.com`
`\nfsd@qq.com`
`\ndf@qq.com`

`\n` being new line. So, in that update matches only the first email.

Comment: Using print_r($invalid_email) I got: Array ( [0] => raphael@live.com [1] => fadfds@qq.com [2] => fsd@qq.com [3] => df@qq.com ). Is that still newlines?

Comment: Yes. Check `View Page Source` and you will see [this](http://pastebin.com/PqQSkG9n).

Answer (score 0):

Because your update query in loop and if each time condition satisfy so it update the status of all four.

Comment: but now it's only updating the 1st one, not all 4

Answer (score 0):

Use **`update_batch()`**, also trim your array values using **`array_map()`**. Try below code,

```
$invalid_email_raw = 'raphael@live.com;
                       fadfds@qq.com;
                       fsd@qq.com;
                       df@qq.com';

$invalid_email = array_map('trim', explode(';', $invalid_email_raw));

$data = array();
foreach($invalid_email as $email)
{
    $data[] = array(
                  "email" => $email,
                  "status" => "unsubscribed"
               );
}

if(!empty($data))
{
    $this->db->update_batch('user', $data, 'email');
}
```

Comment: Please wrap `$this->db->update_batch('user', $data, 'email');` in `if (!empty($data)) {}`, otherwise he might get an error if there are no emails in the `$invalid_email` list.